# (Django) Validation Forms in class based View doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I've created a view where user can sign up that use form with validation functions.
However, those functions don't work.

```
class SignUpPage(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, "signup.html", {'form': form})
    def post(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            redirect('/signup')
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
        ctx = {"form": form}
        return render(request, "signup.html", ctx)
```

The form:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=True)
    email = forms.CharField(label="email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password Again", max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'password'}))
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(label="Date of birth", required=True, widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=YEARS, attrs={'class': 'date-select'}))

def validate_email(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email=data).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already registered")
    return data

def validate_age(self):
    user_date = str(self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'])
    year = int(user_date[0:4])
    month = int(user_date[5:7])
    day = int(user_date[8:10])
    today = dt.today()

    if int(today.year) - year < 18:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must be 18 years old to have an account")
    elif int(today.year) - year == 18 and int(today.month) - month < 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must be 18 years old to have an account")
    elif int(today.year) - year == 18 and int(today.month) - month == 0 and int(today.day) - day < 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must be 18 years old to have an account")
    else:
        return user_date
```

Can someone explain me why those validate functions don't work?
I've even tried with:

```
    def validate_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if data == "abc":
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already registered")
        return data
```

By writting 'abc' in input field.

or:

```
data = self.cleaned_data['email']
```

HTML code for more details:

```
   <form action="" method="post" class="formField">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}
                <div class="s-password">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="show-password" onclick="showPassword()">
                    <label for id="s-password">Show Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-btn-wrapper">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-form">Sign Up</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="check" name="remember">
                    <label for id="remember">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <footer class="form-footer">
                    <p>Already have an account <a href="/login">Login now</a></p>
                </footer>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
```

You are creating the form again when it is not valid, but without passing any post data to it. The validators probably work fine, but you're masking it when recreating your form again.

To fix that issue, simply remove those 2 lines, they are not needed here, as your `GET` path is separated from `POST` path in your view.

Comment: Also that `request.POST or None` should simply be `request.POST`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in my case. After removing those lines, and add print(form.is_valid) got True.

Comment: Are you sure your HTML form is using POST to submit data?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the form to an empty form when form is not valid

```
def post(self, request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # User creation logic ...
        return redirect('/signup') # Your success url page after user is created

    # If this code is executed it means form was not valid
    ctx = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "signup.html", ctx) # Your sign up page to display validation error messages
```